# Couldn't get correct system time and time set by user

Tags: iphone, time, timezone, datepicker

Im working on an app in which i want to fire local-notification on time set by user im just facing problem in getting correct time , So what im doing is this:

```
NSDateFormatter *current = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[current setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[current setDateFormat:@"HH:MM:SS"];
NSDate *systemTime = [NSDate date];
[current setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

NSLog(@"Current time %@" ,[current stringFromDate:systemTime]);
temp = [timeSetter date];//this temp is NSDATE object

NSLog(@"USer time %@" ,[current stringFromDate:temp]);
value = [temp timeIntervalSinceDate:systemTime];//This value is Nstimeinterval instance/obj.
```

And when im printing this through NSLog these are the results which i've recieved[image: Now you can c 23.11.31.323 is actual system time and im getting 23.02.32. Please help me , Thanks in advance]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code, and reproduced a similar result. Your problem is with the `-setDateFormat:` method - it should be `[current setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"]` - this works OK for me. 
In date format strings M = month (02 = February), m = minute, S = fractions of a second and s = seconds.

If you look at the Apple documentation on [date formatting](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1), you'll see that the format strings are determined in a Unicode standard. They link to various versions; the most recent is [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Thank you very much Rich it is now perfectly working :). Now my concept is much clear about datepicker . Thank you :)